# how to append images from variables to a list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I tried this way but it didn't work:

```
  var imglunch = new Image();
  imglunch.src = "../images/faciliteit_lunch.png";
  var imgdiner = new Image();
  imgdiner.src = "../images/faciliteit_diner.png";
  $('.greenfluxlist').append('<li id="' + element.Identifier + '"><a href="bla.html" rel="external">' + imglunch + imgdiner + '</a></li>');
```

Anyone know how to add it?

Comment: i think you can use just src attr of image tag. "<img src="+ path1 +"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply let's use the jQuery function to create your img elements:

```
var imglunch = $( '<img />' );
imglunch.attr( 'src', '../images/faciliteit_lunch.png' );

var imgdiner = $( '<img />' );
imgdiner.attr( 'src', '../images/faciliteit_diner.png' );

$('.greenfluxlist').append('<li id="' + element.Identifier + '"><a href="bla.html" rel="external"></a></li>');
$( '#' + element.Identifier + ' > a' ).append( imglunch ).append( imgdiner );
```

Or you can append your html code all in once:

```
$('.greenfluxlist').append('<li id="' + element.Identifier + '"><a href="bla.html" rel="external"><img src="../images/faciliteit_lunch.png" /><img src="../images/faciliteit_diner.png" /></a></li>');
```